# Setup TLS on existing Nginx ingress controller in AKS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks, ingress-controller

I have deployed Nginx Ingress Controller with Helm in AKS without enabling TLS. Now I want to update the Controller to mount the TLS certificate as Kubernetes secrets, like below -

```
controller:
  extraVolumes:
      - name: secrets-store-inline
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "azure-tls"
  extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: secrets-store-inline
        mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
        readOnly: true
```

Is there any way to update the Ingress Controller?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and what exactly did you try?

Comment: K8s version: 1.21.2 
I have deployed nginx ingress controller with helm. Now I want to enable TLS on it. The certificate is stored in Azure Key Vault. I'm using 'secrets-store.csi.k8s.io' driver to access the certificate and the certificate needs to be mounted in the nginx controller as TLS secret.  [See this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-nginx-tls)

I want to bind the certificate directly to the ingress controller. As I already have deployed it without binding the certificate, looking for a way to update the ingress controller.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to update the Ingress Controller?

Yes, based on [this official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#when-a-reload-is-required) you need to add TLS section to existing Ingress and then reload it (reload should take place automatically):

> The next list describes the scenarios when a reload is required:
>
> - New Ingress Resource Created.
> - **TLS section is added to existing Ingress.**
> - Change in Ingress annotations that impacts more than just upstream configuration. For instance  `load-balancer`  annotation does not require a reload.
> - A path is added/removed from an Ingress.
> - An Ingress, Service, Secret is removed.
> - Some missing referenced object from the Ingress is available, like a Service or Secret.
> - A Secret is updated.

---

**EDIT:**

I have reproduced this situation.
First I have created simple ingress with following `ingress.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing-1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: app-1
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

Then I have run `kubectl get ingress` and here is the output:

```
NAME    CLASS   HOSTS             ADDRESS        PORTS     AGE
ing-1   nginx   www.example.com   35.X.X.X       80        3m
```

In this step I had working ingress without TLS (only working port 80). Then I have created  `tls.yaml` for TLS (I have used self signed certs, you need to use your certs and domain):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls
data:
  tls.crt: |
    <my cert>
  tls.key: |
    <my key>
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

I have run in by `kubectl apply -f tls.yaml` and then I had changed `ingress.yaml` as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing-1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: app-1
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
    # This section is only required if TLS is to be enabled for the Ingress
  tls:
   - hosts:
     - www.example.com
     secretName: tls
```

I have added the TLS section. Then I have run `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml` and after few second I could see this output when running `kubectl get ingress`:

```
NAME    CLASS   HOSTS             ADDRESS        PORTS     AGE
ing-1   nginx   www.example.com   35.239.7.126   80, 443   18m
```

TLS is working. In the logs I can see this message:

```
Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ing-1", UID:"84966fae-e135-47bb-8110-bf372de912c8", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"11306", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

Ingress reloaded automatically :)

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak  Could you please provide me any docs link which shows, how to update and reload the Ingress Controller? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2612) should help you.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar, My previous link showed how to do this manually, but it is not recommended. The Kubernetes Ingress Controller should update automatically.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar, I have edited my answer (I have added reproduction section). Now should be clear ;)

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Thank you so much for all this hard work. Thing is that I already knew this process of updating the Ingress, but I don't want to do this. I want to update the **Ingress Controller**, not the Ingress. As I previously mentioned that the certificate should be bound to **Ingress Controller**, not to the Ingress.

Comment: [this doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/) should help you in this case.